# Cannot disable linting warning from pylsp

Tags: lua, lint, neovim, language-server-protocol, python-language-server

I am trying to disable the warning from pylsp that my line is too long.
However, evertime I open or save a python file I notice a message that pyflake, mccabe and pycodestyle are completed and I get a warning that some lines are too long.

I cannot seem to find a way to disable this.
Can someone tell me what I am missing or give an example on how they did it?

My init.lua is from kickstart.vim, where I added the following

```
pylsp = {
    configurationSources = { 'flake8' },
    plugins = {
        flake8 = {
            enabled = false,
            ignore = { 'E501', 'E231' },
            maxLineLength = 88,
        },
        black = {enabled = true},
        autopep8 = { enabled = false },
        mccabe = {enabled = false},
        pycodestyle = {
            enabled = false,
            ignore = { 'E501', 'E231' },
            maxLineLength = 88,
        },
        pyflakes = {enabled = false},
    }
},
```

installed packages (mason.vim):

- black
- flake8
- yapf
- python-lsp-server

Comment: How do you go about this?

Comment: I am not using pylsp, but jedi-language-server at the moment